# Grenular permissions on Android. why not?

Tags: android

From what I uderstand, there is no way to do something like

```
if(have certain permission){
    //do something that requires the permission
}
```

where the application  can request optional permissions.
For example I want to track usage of my app only if the user accepts to being tracked. But still allow the user to download and use the app with tracking disabled if he dosen't agree.
Is this at all possible ? If not, what is the reasoning behind not supporting this feature ?

EDIT: to clarify, Im referring to Android permissions, like using the camera or looking at the contact list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [Android documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/security/permissions.html):

> The permissions required by an application are declared statically in
>   that application, so they can be known up-front at install time and
>   will not change after that.

User needs to be informed about the permissions while installing the application. Asking them at run time would be a security risk. A rouge application can use `clickjacking` to make user accept the permission..

Comment: ok. so no asking the user to grant permissions at run time. that makes sense. but why not allow for optional permissions during download (i.e, at the play store), or install ? kind of like facebook optional permissions.

Comment: There is already a issue for that, check out following link http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=6266 you can read about lot of point of views in the comments..

Comment: thanks for pointing me to the discussion. interesting stuff there.

Answer (score 0):

If your are really talking about Android permissions, such as camera. Use the :
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-feature-element.html

```
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" android:required="false" />
```

This means the app can also be used on a device which does not have a camera.

For your example (asking the user permission to track him/her)
You can do this with any language you want. Because your permission is not something like `Android permissions`.

Just ask the user a question, with a `checkbox`. Save the value of the `checkbox` (using `SharedPreferences`) and use the value in your `if` statement.

Comment: I was referring to the android permissions.

Comment: Your example (user tracking) is not available in Android. If your are refering to optional Android permissions, such as: the app can use a camera, but it is not required. Meaning you can install it on a device without a camera and on a device with a camera.